# Is there any tool that give us webdriver code from a site

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

is there any tool which give me all the elements (id, xpath, cssSelector, className) that were used in the site.

I dont want to every time record using selenium or go in the firebug to check the best element that i can use in the script.

Is it possible with the help of tool ?

Thanks

Comment: F12 button, or FireBug extension may be helpful. Still you need to select element first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any consistent tool that does such as for Record and play tools, they seem to derive easier Xpath .i.e not optimized or consistent and tests don't often run more than once.

best suggestion is to write consistent Xpath or locators using unique attributes that'll always exist
Here are links that might be helpful.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please try using firepath which is an addon for firefox. This gives an elements id(other attributes),xpath ,Css and sizzle. 
Link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/

Comment: Thanks for the link..I tried it and seem to be very useful to get the absolute xpath.. Thanks a Lot